# SQL - ROW_NUMBER that is used in a multi-condition LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]Two tables store different properties for each product: CTI_ROUTING_VIEW and ORD_MACH_OPS

They are both organized by SPEC_NO > MACH_SEQ_NO but the format of the Sequence number is different for each table so it can't be used for a JOIN. ORCH_MACH_OPS has MACHINE and PASS_NO, meaning if a product goes through the same machine twice, the row with the higher SEQ_NO will be PASS_NO 2, 3, etc. CTI_ROUTING_VIEW does not offer PASS_NO, but I can achieve the desired result with:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [SPEC_NO]
      ,[SPEC_PART_NO]
      ,[MACH_NO]
      ,[MACH_SEQ_NO]
      ,[BLANK_WID]
      ,[BLANK_LEN]
      ,[NO_OUT_WID]
      ,[NO_OUT_LEN]
      ,[SU_MINUTES]
      ,[RUN_SPEED]
      ,[NO_COLORS]
      ,[PRINTDIEID]
      ,[CUTDIEID]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MACH_NO ORDER BY MACH_SEQ_NO) as PASS_NO
  FROM [CREATIVE].[dbo].[CTI_ROUTING_VIEW]
```

I would think that I could use this artificial PASS_NO as a JOIN condition, but I can't seem to get it to come through. This is my first time using ROW_NUMBER() so I'm just wondering if I'm doing something wrong in the JOIN syntax.

```
SELECT rOrd.[SPEC_NO]
      ,rOrd.[MACH_SEQ_NO]
      ,rOrd.[WAS_REROUTED]
      ,rOrd.[NO_OUT]
      ,rOrd.[PART_COMP_FLG]
      ,rOrd.[SCHED_START]
      ,rOrd.[SCHED_STOP]
      ,rOrd.[MACH_REROUTE_FLG]
      ,rOrd.[MACH_DESCR]
      ,rOrd.REPLACED_MACH_NO
      ,rOrd.MACH_NO
      ,rOrd.PASS_NO
      ,rWip.MAX_TRX_DATETIME
      ,ISNULL(rWip.NET_FG_SUM*rOrd.NO_OUT,0) as NET_FG_SUM
      ,CASE
        WHEN rCti.BLANK_WID IS NULL then 'N//A'
        ELSE CONCAT(rCti.BLANK_WID, ' X ', rCti.BLANK_LEN)
       END AS SIZE
     ,ISNULL(rCti.PRINTDIEID,'N//A') as PRINTDIEID
     ,ISNULL(rCti.CUTDIEID, 'N//A') as CUTDIEID
     ,rStyle.DESCR as STYLE
     ,ISNULL(rCti.NO_COLORS, 0) as NO_COLORS
     ,CAST(CONCAT(rOrd.ORDER_NO,'-',rOrd.ORDER_PART_NO) as varchar) as ORD_MACH_KEY
  FROM [CREATIVE].[dbo].[ORD_MACH_OPS] as rOrd
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
       [SPEC_NO]
      ,[SPEC_PART_NO]
      ,[MACH_NO]
      ,MACH_SEQ_NO
      ,[BLANK_WID]
      ,[BLANK_LEN]
      ,[NO_COLORS]
      ,[PRINTDIEID]
      ,[CUTDIEID]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MACH_NO ORDER BY MACH_SEQ_NO) as PASS_NO
    FROM [CREATIVE].[dbo].[CTI_ROUTING_VIEW]) as rCti
    ON rCti.SPEC_NO = rOrd.SPEC_NO
    and rCti.MACH_NO =
        CASE 
            WHEN rOrd.REPLACED_MACH_NO is null then rOrd.MACH_NO
            ELSE rOrd.REPLACED_MACH_NO
        END
    and rCti.PASS_NO  = rOrd.PASS_NO
    LEFT JOIN INVENTORY_ITEM_TAB as rTab
    ON rTab.SPEC_NO = rOrd.SPEC_NO
    LEFT JOIN STYLE_DESCRIPTION as rStyle
    ON rStyle.DESCR_CD = rTab.STYLE_CD
      LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
        JOB_NUMBER
        ,FORM_NO
        ,TRX_ORIG_MACH_NO
        ,PASS_NO
        ,SUM(GROSS_FG_QTY-WASTE_QTY) as NET_FG_SUM
        ,MAX(TRX_DATETIME) as MAX_TRX_DATETIME
      FROM WIP_MACH_OPS
      WHERE GROSS_FG_QTY <> 0
      GROUP BY JOB_NUMBER, FORM_NO, TRX_ORIG_MACH_NO, PASS_NO) as rWip
    ON rWip.JOB_NUMBER = rOrd.ORDER_NO
    and rWip.FORM_NO = rOrd.ORDER_PART_NO
    and rWip.TRX_ORIG_MACH_NO = rOrd.MACH_NO
    and rWip.PASS_NO = rOrd.PASS_NO
  WHERE rOrd.SCHED_START > DATEADD(DAY, -20, GETDATE())
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "can't get it to come through". It will help if you can remove everything except rOrd and rCti so you can narrow it down to the join you're concerned about. Additionally, consider using COALESCE instead of CASE WHEN in the join.

Comment: To clarify the first part:
When I leave out the ,ROW_NUMBER()...as PASS_NO line and the matching "and" JOIN line, the columns PRINTDIEID, CUTDIEID, NO_COLORS, etc all match the way I would expect them to as long as the routing only has 1 of each MACH_NO. As soon as there's multiple passes on a MACH_NO, I get double matching of all the rCti columns. So I need to the JOIN to consider PASS_NO as well to stop that.

I only learned the CASE function two days ago and I've seen COALESCE but haven't used it before. I'll look into it when I get back to work tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a second partition.
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SPEC_NO, MACH_NO ORDER BY MACH_SEQ_NO) as PASS_NO